# Problem with Comment link in Blog

Tags: comments, blog-page

I have all the settings setup to allow comments on my Blog postings. However, when you click on the link to post a comment nothing happens.
Attached is my comments.php file
Also the site is www.djjigs.com
Thanks in Advance!

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h2 id="comments-title">
        <?php comments_number(__('No Comments', 'stylico'), __('1 Comment', 'stylico'), __('% Comments', 'stylico')); ?>
    </h2>
    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-above">
        <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'stylico' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'stylico') ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'stylico') ); ?></div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <ol class="commentlist">
        <?php wp_list_comments( 'callback=stylico_comment' ); ?>
    </ol>

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below">
        <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'stylico'); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'stylico') ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'stylico') ); ?></div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    elseif ( ! comments_open() && ! is_page() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
?>
<p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'stylico'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php comment_form( array( 'comment_notes_after'  => '', 'label_submit' => __('Send Comment', 'stylico') ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if you're talking about the comment reply or a normal (non-reply) comment.

Anyway, here's how you'd register the comment reply script from your functions.php file:

```
function wpse60406_scripts()
{
    # Comment reply script
    if ( 
        is_singular() // Use is_single() if this shouldn't work for pages
        AND get_option( 'thread_comments' ) 
    )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse60406_scripts' );
```